# MODULE NOT FOUND when importing "firebase/auth/react-native" module

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Got MODULE NOT FOUND for the line :

```
import { getReactNativePersistence, initializeAuth } from "firebase/auth/react-native";
```

On the next screenshot you can see my 'firebase-config.js' file

[firebase-config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0ECR.png)

I saw that firebase module is updated a lot so I search for new ways of importing this module but without succcess

Comment: I checked https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start, https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence and https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage, but don't see anything like what you're using. Where did you get that import syntax from (as maybe you're using a different SDK)? If not, I recommend following the code in the relevant docs  that I linked.